# Exiting app after completion of all crouton toasts

Tags: java, android, crouton

I am using Crouton as alternative to native android toasts. I have to display 5-6 croutons one after the another and then call `System.exit(0)` to exit my app.

The problem is, I see first crouton for 1-2 seconds and the app just exits! The rest croutons aren't displayed at all. This is because when the code is being executed the undisplayed croutons are added to queue. And when it comes to `System.exit(0)` it exits the app without displaying those queued croutons. I have tried searching for solution for this and came across a solution in which I have to create a new thread, then sleep it for time = sum of durations of necessary croutons and then call System.exit in that thread. But then if I have more or less croutons in another situation then that becomes useless.

So can anyone think of a solution?

Comment: Please add the code you're using.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have to quit the app?

In general, in Android, applications should not quit, and show not provide a way for the user to quit them. Quitting an app is handled by the system when the user navigates away from it and goes back to the home screen.

If your application must quit (for example, because of an unexpected condition it can't deal with) and you want to make sure the user sees the information, then the best approach would be to use an AlertDialog to display the information.

So, long story short: revise your UI... if you're sure that this is the right way to do it, then simply don't call System.exit(0). Just show the toasts and then stick around. Eventually the system will decide to quit your app when memory is needed.